# Spring Security Concurrency On Different Browsers

Tags: browser, concurrency, spring-security

I have a web application using spring webflow and spring security. I have a problem with concurrency and here's the scenario.

When I log in an and go to an edit page, and when my account was already restricted for that operation, I am not supposed to be able to perform the operation already. I see that since my ROLE save in the session was loaded during log in so this would naturally happen. What's the best practice for this. Shall I query for my role and replace that in the session FOR EVERY critical operation or restricted operation? Is this not an overhead to the server?

Comment: You want to restrict the access to a page to one user at time?

Comment: Not necessarily. As long as I can keep track of the user's access rights anytime anywhere. So do I have to query a user's access rights for every page load? I was thinking of a single sign on but I don't know if it's easy to imlement using spring and spring webflow

Answer (score 0):

- Keep cache of `<user id, timestamp>` of users whose permissions were changed recently. Let cache entries expire after a twice amount of session expiration time.
- Add custom filter that recognizes sessions having existing `SecurityContext`:

  - If session `SecurityContext` contains `Principal` whose user id is in the recently changed cache and session's `getLastAccessTime()` is earlier than a change timestamp, explicitly re-authenticate the user with a new authorities.

This solution will take care of both permissions upgrade and downgrade scenarios.

You may see a good example of user in `org.springframework.security.web.authentication.switchuser.SwitchUserFilter`